# How in PhpStorm to render selected text into other spelling?

Tags: phpstorm

Seems PhpStorm 2019 has functionality when some text selected, like “showDetailedMapComponentRestrictions”
by some operation to render this text into “ShowDetailedMapComponentRestrictions”
or “show-detailed-map-component-restrictions”
How can I trigger this functionality for selected text/code ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate plugin for that.

There are quite a few that can do this kind of transformation. For example:

- [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation)
- [CamelCase](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160-camelcase)
- etc [1](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=idea&search=camel) / [2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=idea&search=case)